# What are Recursive Lexer Rules in ANTLR4 good for?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Just beginning with ANTLR4. Found that lexer rules can be recursive https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md#recursive-lexer-rules. What is the use case to use recursive lexer rules instead of recursive parser rules? Dont you loose all the information when using lexer recursive rules?

Comment: Nested comments or nested literals (like `%q(this (is a) string)` in Ruby).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by sepp2k: besides nested string literals, nested comments are 1 of the use cases:

```
COMMENT
 : '/*' ( COMMENT | . )*? '*/'
 ;
```